# Meteor + processing.js - How to Integrate?

Tags: javascript, canvas, meteor, processing, public

I'm trying to integrate processing.js and meteor and I'm having issues with it.

First let me show how processing.js exports projects and how my meteor projects are configured:

A normal web-export using processing.js is:

```
web-export
    artWork1.pde
    index.html
    beautiful.png
    file.xml
    audio.wav
    processing.js
```

Everything working together.

My meteor configuration.

```
Webapp
    -client
        -views
            -artWork1
                artWork1.html
            -artWork2
                artWork2.html
        main.html
    -collections
    -lib
    -server
    -public
        -img
            beautiful.png
        -js
            processing.js
            artWork1.pde
            file.xml
        -audio
            audio.wav
        -data
```

My Main

```
main.html

<head>
    <title>Poesias</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="/js/processing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>
```

My artWork.html

```
artWork1.html

<template name="artWork1">

        <canvas id="artwork1" data-processing-sources="/js/artWork1.pde" width="768" height="1024">
        </canvas>


</template>
```

So I don' know how to configure this properly, if someone has an idea please let me understand.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend integrating via the package manager, instead of trying to manually insert it yourself. [Atmosphere](http://www.atmospherejs.com) is a package catalog for meteor, where you can find packages in general. The specific processing js package seems to be [here](https://atmospherejs.com/bgrayburn/processingjs), and you can add the package via executing `meteor add bgrayburn:processingjs` in the terminal.